# Store table data to a jquery variable

Tags: jquery

I want to store data in a table to a jquery variable, the code im using is as below, but this code is storing all table tags like tr, td and everything to the variable, where as i just need to store the data in td tag in text format to a jquery variable..can anyone help?

```
var table = $("#mytable").html();
```

Comment: What do you mean by "jquery variable"? Your `table` variable is just a "variable". Have you tried the `.text()` method instead of `.html()`?

Answer (score 1):

You can collect the cell values like this:

```
arr = new Array();
$("td").each(function () {
    t = $(this).text();
    arr.push(t);
});

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: hi Balint, the code u gave is working correct, but on my table i have applied pagination, and so im getting only the values which are displayed in the current view of table, not the values on the next page of the table, how can i do it?

Comment: are they hidden html elements or are you loading them with AJAX?

Comment: hi ballint, now i get the table data in the array and im basically generating a pdf for this table, but the pdf wont show data in tabular form..can u help?

Comment: if you have a problem with the PDF rendering, then you should open another question... more people will read it then in a comment!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the text, use `.text()` instead of `.html()`:

```
var table = $("#mytable").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var table_data;
$("#mytable td").each(function(){
   table_data += $(this).text();
});

console.log(table_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :-

```
var header = Array();

$("#mytable tr th").each(function(i, v){
    header[i] = $(this).text();
})

alert(header);

var data = Array();

$("#mytable tr").each(function(i, v){
    data[i] = Array();
    $(this).children('td').each(function(ii, vv){
    data[i][ii] = $(this).text();
 }); 
})

alert(data);
```