# Extract data from a particular column using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is table :-

```
    var thetable = "";
    thetable= thetable + "<tr><th>Audit ID</th><th>Date Modified</th><th>Auditor</th><th>Franchisee Name</th><th>Store ID</th><th>Template Name</th><th>Description</th></tr>";
```

How do i extract data from a particular column using javascript?
I am new to this so any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Using jQuery :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35523260/how-to-create-an-array-containing-the-value-of-td-element/35523331#35523331

Comment: What data? Which column? Is the table in the DOM or are you trying to get it from the string?

Comment: Since you mention that you're new, I would recommend taking a step back and see if you can avoid the issue in your given circumstance. For example, if you are building a site, I would recommend using an object to represent your data. You can then lookup data freely in a far cleaner/more maintainable way and generate the HTML dynamically. Otherwise, the answer could be one below, or if you're using jQuery:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17486654/store-table-data-to-a-jquery-variable

Comment: thanks all, i wasn't clear on how to frame my question. I'll be more careful.
I'll have a look into the link @A Small Shell Script

Answer (score 5, accepted):

take a look on this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/8cyL7o7s/)

HTML

```
<table id="mytable" border="1">
  <tr>
   <th>Audit ID</th>
   <th>Date Modified</th>
   <th>Auditor</th>
 </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="colA_rowA">1</td>
    <td id="colB_rowA">2</td>
    <td id="colC_rowA">3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="colA_rowB">4</td>
    <td id="colB_rowB">5</td>
    <td id="colC_rowB">6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

JavaScript

```
// Option one by cell id
alert(document.getElementById("colB_rowA").innerHTML);

// Another option to run on all table
GetCellValues();

function GetCellValues() {
  var table = document.getElementById('mytable');
  for (var r = 0, n = table.rows.length; r < n; r++) {
    for (var c = 0, m = table.rows[r].cells.length; c < m; c++) {
      alert(table.rows[r].cells[c].innerHTML);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`innerHTML` is your friend. A sample snippet for a table with id=**mytable**.

```
function GetCellValues() {
    var table = document.getElementById('mytable');
    for (var r = 0, n = table.rows.length; r < n; r++) {
        for (var c = 0, m = table.rows[r].cells.length; c < m; c++) {
            alert(table.rows[r].cells[c].innerHTML);
        }
    }
}
```